# FQL like operator

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Can someone tell me why this works:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND strpos(lower(name),"jo") >=0
```

however this does not:

```
"SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE strpos(lower(url), 'sephora') >= 0"
```

When I put it in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

I get this response:

Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

however "url" in indeed indexable.

any thoughts? I've already scoured stackoverflow but no answers found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site isn't indexable, it's only selectable. It doesn't have an * next to it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/

you need to use url or id as the indexable column, so basically one of those needs to be in your where clause.

Comment: typo... actually it should have been URL from the start. edited the question. the result is still the same.

Comment: Then my guess is because, the top example isn't using functions on the index. So WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) acts as the index and then uses the rest of the where clause. So running SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url='sephora' and strpos(lower(url), 'sephora') >= 0 would be a valid query(though obviously wouldn't return any results as url='sephora' isn't a full url) so it looks like you need to change your query I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

FQL != SQL  You can't a a WHERE on any column you want.  Not surprising considering the performance required with so many concurrent writers, I mean, one person in every ten in the world has signed up.

The problem in the second example is that a field used as a parameter in one of the string functions loses its indexability.  It has to be the column itself.